How to tell if a mobile user has scrolled up or down
I'm making a scroll detector for a website and I need to make it work for mobile. So, if a desktop user scrolled down with their mouse, it'd console log it, and vice versa. Here is the desktop code for you to analyze:
  window.addEventListener("wheel", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.deltaY < 0) {
      console.log('up')
    } else {
      console.log('down')
    }
  }
});

How would I do this for mobile devices such as phones or tablets?

This question is similar to: Detect touch scroll up or down. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Read about intersection observer API of JavaScript, it records all the information that you need

@DarkBee, Sorry for making a duplicate question. I didn't see that post when I previously searched my issue.

For mobile devices, you can detect scrolling by listening to the touchmove event. This event is similar to the wheel event but for touch screens.


// Function to handle scroll direction
function handleScroll(direction) {
  console.log(direction);
}

// Desktop: Listen to wheel event
window.addEventListener("wheel", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.deltaY < 0) {
    handleScroll('up');
  } else {
    handleScroll('down');
  }
});

// Mobile: Listen to touchmove event
let touchStartY = 0;
window.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
  touchStartY = event.touches[0].clientY;
}, false);

window.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const touchEndY = event.changedTouches[0].clientY;
  if (touchStartY > touchEndY) {
    handleScroll('mobile down');
  } else {
    handleScroll('mobile up');
  }
}, false);



